# Sending object and commands to a server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm new to Java socket programming, looking for a good approach to send either commands or objects to a server via Java sockets. The objects shall be stored on the server, the commands shall request data from the server.

At first the server doesn't know what he receives in the input stream, so he has to examine it, but I'm not sure how to do that. I would take the input stream, convert it to a String and then check the first chars to decide if they form a command or not. The problem I have is that InputStream.toString() returns something like 
java.net.SocketInputStream@437d51a6

Thanks for your opinions and ideas.

Here is my first bad approach:

```
 String input = inputStream.toString();  // this doesn't work
 String startString =  
   input.toString().substring(0, Math.min( input.toString().length(),3));

    if(startString.equals(COMMAND)){
    // process command, e.g. to request data from the server
    }
    else {
     // extract object to send data to the server
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem here? in sending object? or in identifying whether this is the required object?

Comment: can you provide some code snippet you have tried? Will give us better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how this works. The trick is to wrap the inputStream into a Scanner object like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream);
String str = s.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be creating classes for data types as well as for commands.

You can then use writeObject method of ObjectOutputStream ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html ) to send command/data to server using default Java serialization (that's assuming that needed classes are also present in the server classpath).

Server can then get them from ObjectInputStream and easily act accordingly to their type. You will have to cast them from Object type, but you can check their real type using .getClass() or instanceof if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, but all this works. I just wanted to know if my approach to request data from a server is good or maybe naïve, because I decided to send a simple String as a request command.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with "simple" text commands. Have a look at SMTP or HTTP, it's just plain text.

And there is a good reason for that: You can just *telnet* into your server, and type in the commands. This is a great help, because you can query your server without a special client.

Example for *telnet* into a local web server (I just typed in "GET /")

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<html>


<body>
  <h1>Welcome  on xxx</h1>
</body>

</html>

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Further your service is not tied to a special language or a special binary format respectively.